# How do I pass a constant as a variable?

Tags: php, variables, curl, constants

aI want to set up a generic wrapper class method for setting options in curl requests, like so;

```
curl_setopt($curl_handles[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

However, I want to be able to pass the constant via the parameter in my method, so something like;

```
protected function set_option($i, $OPTION)
{

    curl_setopt($curl_handles[$i], $OPTION, true);  

}
```

Is this even possible? I haven't tried this, but I get the feeling this won't work. Can a name of constant be stored in a variable like this?

Comment: -1. In the time it took you to write this question you could already have tried it out.

Comment: Is that really a reason to -1 the question? I had a question, and I explained it clearly. The time it would take someone to read the question/answer might be quicker than trying it. Whether or not it would have been quicker for me is my choice, and doesn't detract from the question. It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Yes, the -1 is my choice.

Comment: Your prerogative. Others may find my question useful. Neg repping the question to neg rep me doesn't seem much in the community spirit of how Stack Overflow works, but like you say, it's your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to pass a constant into a method parameter? What you have should work just fine.

```
protected function set_option($i, $OPTION)
{
    curl_setopt($curl_handles[$i], $OPTION, true);  
}

set_option(1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER);
```

Comment: Yep, that's it exactly. I wasn't even sure if that would work. I didn't know if you could store a constant name in a variable.

Comment: You aren't actually storing the *name*, you are storing the *value*. `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is a variable that defines a value. When the interpreter parses the `set_option()` call it first looks up the value of `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`. The *value* is then passed to the function, which is stored in `$OPTION`.

Comment: No constant __name__ is actually stored in any variable here, it's passing a constant __value__ to a function, that will then be used in that function